# Autocomplete does not detect changes to the source object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using `jQuery`'s `autocomplete()` method on a text field with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects)` as the source:

```
$(function() {
    $("#project").autocomplete({source: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects)});
}
```

The `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects)` method returns an array of the `projects` object's property names.

This works just fine. However:

If the user enters a new value in the field (ie, a value that is not already a property of the `projects` object), then the value gets added as a property when a button is clicked (the page is not reloaded). Button click also resets the field. When I try entering a value in the field now, the suggestions list doesn't show the newly added property (unless I call the `autocomplete` method again). How do I resolve this?

Psst. If I assign the value of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects)` to an array, use the array as the source in the autocomplete method and update the array on button click, then the suggestions list shows the newly added value.

The following function handles the button click:

```
$("#clock").click(function() {
    if (!($("#project").val() in projects)) { //If value is not already a property
        projects[$("#project").val()] = $("#skill").val(); //skill is another field
    }
    $('#theForm')[0].reset(); //theForm is the id of the form that contains the fields
}
```

Comment: Please tell me if I need to provide more details

Comment: Please show us the code which is handling the button clicks.

Comment: I think you have to use projects[$("#project").val()] instead of projects["$("#project").val()"]

Comment: yeah changed it, but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I think you already got it working saving Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects) in a separate array and keep updating that array. That's the right way to do it.It works that way because you gave the source as a reference to the array and you're changing the same array. It doesn't work just giving Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects) because that will create a reference to a new array (which you will not change, you will just change the projects).

Comment: @mimarcel: Thanks man! you led me to my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mimarcel pointed out, `$("#project").autocomplete({source: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects)});` only created an array that wouldn't change when I updated the `projects` object. In order for the suggestions list to reflect changes on the object, I had to use a callback, like so:

```
$('#project').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        response(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects));
    }
});
```

Comment: It's great you can use a callback function as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the `source` option of the autocomplete after the `localArr` is updated:

```
$("#project").autocomplete("option", "source", localArr);
```

Comment: I have updated the question since. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

After the form is submitted, your page refreshes, so the javascript code runs again, and what your javascript code says is to auto-complete the input field with the elements from the given source. You have to make sure your source now includes the new project the user just added.

PHP example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var projects;
 jQuery(function() {
    projects = {project1: 1, project2: 2, project3: 3, project4: 4};
    <?php if (isset($_GET['project'])): ?>
        projects['<?php echo $_GET['project']?>'] = 'foobar';
    <?php endif ?>
    jQuery("[name=project]").autocomplete({source: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects)});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
   Project: <input type="text" name="project" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['project']) ? $_GET['project'] : ""?>"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I seem to have given you the wrong picture, the page is not reloaded, only the fields are cleared. +1 though